# Get all text in multiline wpf textblock

Tags: wpf

I have Multiline TextBlock,  I want to get all it's lines by code 
Can someone help me?

The TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Name="tb" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                              Name:_____________
                                <LineBreak/>
                                 Mark:____________
          </TextBlock>
```

In C#:

```
text = ((TextBlock)tb).Text;
```

But I got only the first line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var line in tb.Inlines)
{
    if (line is LineBreak)
        s.AppendLine();
    else if (line is Run)
        s.Append(((Run) line).Text);
}
var text = s.ToString();
```

Found it [here](http://developingfor.net/2009/03/23/processing-multiline-text-in-a-wpf-textblock/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display on multiple lines you can use :

```
<TextBlock Name="myText" Text="I go &#x0a; Home " >
```

and sure, you can get all lines by parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here it show 3 possible ways of getting this done. Please use which suits your requirement.

```
1.<LineBreak />
2.TextWrapping="Wrap"
3.TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
```

[here](http://[Here]http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-textblock-control/)